# Is there a way to define required parameter in web.xml in java servlet

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I am trying to create a rest api using a java servlet application. I am working with url pattern mapping using `web.xml` . When I validate parameters I need to do `request.getParameter("name")` and check whether it is `null` and try to match it with only string regex.

I need to know whether there is any way to define the parameter we get from the POST method request in the `web.xml` file. Like `<init-param>` where we define a variable with value, is there a way to match a parameter with regex in `web.xml` file?

Comment: Your Question is not clear. What does the content of a POST parameter have to do with the text of your web.xml file?

Comment: No, you can't. The web descriptor file defines only a servlet mapping.

Comment: Just use JAX-RS API instead of plain Servlet API, then you can use Validation API, else you'll need to homegrow it yourself.